# Destroy Image after loading it to ImageList in C#

Tags: c#, image

I have searched through stackoverflow about ImageLists, I am confused with the answers/replies. 
        I have the following code, what it does is; based on the file extension it grabs the `Icon`. So when I add a file say Hello.pdf, i show the file on a list view with `.pdf` icon similar to windows explorer.

```
private void bwUpdateSmallImageList_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (smImageLock)
        {
            foreach (String ext in _Extension)
            {
                if (!_SmallImageLists.Images.ContainsKey(ext)) // .jpg/.pdf/.doc
                {
                    IntPtr handle;
                    IconSize iSize = IconSize.Small;
                    Icon icon = null;
                    try
                    {
                        icon = FileSystemHelper.IconFromFileExtension(ext, iSize, out handle);
                        if (icon != null)
                        {
                            Image b = icon.ToBitmap() as Image;
                            if (b != null)
                            {
                                _SmallImageLists.Images.Add(ext, b);                                    
                                //b.Dispose();   ****1 call dispose ?
                                //icon.Dispose(); ****2 call dispose ?
                            }
                        }
                        DestroyIcon(handle);
                        // this one is being called
                        //[DllImport("user32.dll")]
                        //private static extern bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);
                    }
                    catch { }//(TargetInvocationException ex)// we dont want to throw exception from a background worker
                            // if it can not grab the icon just leave it blank
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
```

After I have added to the image list, should I dispose/destroy the `Image` variable `b` and also the `Icon` variable `icon`.

I actually didn't find a proper answer, after I have added an icon/image to a `ImageList`, is it copying to the image lists own memory space or it keeps the memory address of the image/icon? `FileSystemHelper.IconFromFileExtension` function looks like following;

```
public static Icon IconFromFileExtension(string fileExtension, IconSize iconSize, out IntPtr handle)
        {
            //Icon icon = null;
            handle = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                if (fileExtension.StartsWith(".") == false)
                    fileExtension = "." + fileExtension;
                SHFILEINFO shFileInfo = new SHFILEINFO();
                SHGetFileInfo(fileExtension,
                                0,
                                ref shFileInfo,
                                (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shFileInfo),
                                SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES | (uint)iconSize);
                handle = shFileInfo.hIcon;
                //icon = Icon.FromHandle(shFileInfo.hIcon);
                //DestroyIcon(handle);// this is wrong, icon needs the handle, can't destroy
                return Icon.FromHandle(shFileInfo.hIcon);
                //return icon; 
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                //return LanganComponent.Properties.Resources.unknown;
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I ask because I am getting `Creation of the ImageList handle did not succeed.` My visual studio is crashing, when I try debugging after getting the crash report in `dev.exe`, it gets to the point where I tried to copy to a `ListView`'s `SmallImageList/LargeImgaeList`.

I have tried disposing by calling `b.Dispose()` and `icon.Dispose()`. But when I do so, I figured out icons are missing. I could have returned `Bitmap` using `System.Drawing.Icon.ToBitmap()`, but I chose to use `Icon` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to dispose the Icon after calling Icon.ToBitmap()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564574/is-it-safe-to-dispose-the-icon-after-calling-icon-tobitmap)

Comment: Are you mixing managed and unmanaged code?

Comment: yes I am mixing them both. I have been testing it. To my surprise, if I comment out `b.Dispose()` and `icon.Dispose()`, I get Invalid parameter exception. I don't have a clear understanding, but seems like disposing after adding to the Image List disposes `Handle` which is very strange. But I am more testing to prove my theory.

Comment: Its may or may not be relevant, but helped me understand more after reading the [story](http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2007/11/29/The-Mysterious-Parameter-Is-Not-Valid-Exception.aspx), since I was also getting `System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid`